# Automorphisms of elliptic curves in characteristic 2 and 3

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over a field $k$ of characteristic $p = 2$ or $3$, and suppose $j(E) = 0\equiv 1728\mod p$.

In this case, $Aut(E)$ has size either 12 or 24.

Let $\omega$ be an invariant differential for $E$. How does $Aut(E)$ act on $\omega$? (Ie, it should multiply it by some nonzero element of $k$. What is that number?)

What is the structure of $Aut(E)$ as a group scheme (over $k$)?

Comment: By rigidity and density of the collection of finite etale $n$-torsion for $n>0$ not divisible by char($k$), the Aut-scheme for a polarized abelian variety $(A,\phi)$ over any field $k$ is finite etale.  You ask about the action $G:={\rm{Aut}}_{E/k}\rightarrow k^{\times}$ on ${\rm{Lie}}(E)$. The order of $G$ is divisible by $p={\rm{char}}(k)$ and one other prime $p'$. The normal $p$-Sylow acts trivially, and the cyclic $p'$-Sylow acts faithfully by Lemma 3.3 of Edixhoven's "Neron models and tame ramification" and faithfulness of the formal group; see Wikipedia for "ss elliptic curve".

Comment: P.s. if you are wondering what the structure of the group is over the algebraic closure as an abstract group, it is: https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/SmallGroup(12,1)

Comment: For the benefit of Magma users who find this post in the future, I note that this group is obtained in Magma by the command  SmallGroup(12,1);  (M.D.'s comment leads to similar GAP code for the group, and Magma's SmallGroup identifiers are the same as GAP's)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are exact formulas for the automorphisms, for example in *The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves* Appendix A, proof of Proposition 1.2. From those you can write down explicitly the action of $\text{Aut}(E)$ on $\omega=dx/(2y+a_1x+a_3)$. Here's the characteristic 3 case. $E$ has a Weierstrass equation of the form 
$$ E:y^2=x^3+a_4x+a_6. $$
(In characteristic 3, this curve has $j(E)=0$.) Then $\text{Aut}(E)$ is the set of automorphisms of the form
$$ x\mapsto u^2 x+r\quad\text{and}\quad y\mapsto u^3y $$
with $(u,r)$ satisfying
$$ u^4=1\quad\text{and}\quad r^3+a_4r+(1-u^6)a_6 = 0.$$
So in this case, $\omega=dx/2y$ and the map $\phi_{u,r}$ associated to $(u,r)$ acts via 
$$ \phi_{u,r}^*\omega = u^{-1}\omega. $$

To answer your second question, the group scheme structure is
$$ \text{Aut}(E)=\frac{k[u,r]}{\bigl(u^4-1,r^3+a_4r+(1-u^6)a_6 \bigr)}.$$

The calculation for characteristic 2, which I will leave for you, is similar.